# Camera2 API: Keep autorotation on, but don't rotate camera preview and buttons

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am looking for a solution to keep the SCREEN ORIENTATION in auto mode, but that the preview of the camera does not rotate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` under the activity tag in your manifest file (i.e. AndroidManifest.xml) if you want to make your activity's orientation fixed (this is the activity in which the preview of camera is being shown by you).

Like for example -

```
<activity
            android:name="com.something.camera.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: I want to make it variable: So the Capture Button from the buttom goes left, when rotating to landscape...Also my preview gets rotated and I see it rotated 90 degress to much

Comment: For that you can make two layouts (for the same activity file) - one for portrait and the other for landscape and then configure or place your views accordingly as per your need or requirement.

Link: https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-portrait-landscape-screens

Ctrl + F --> Using a Landscape Layout File (when the above link is opened).

And for the rotation issue (90 degrees), you need to apply some logic that you can easily find on net to have the proper camera preview.

Answer (score 0):

Use rotation animation [SEAMLESS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#ROTATION_ANIMATION_SEAMLESS), and implement landscape and portrait UIs that carefully place the preview window in the same place.